# How to take image from imageView and store it to firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to pick image from imageview rather than gallery or a folder. The reason for that is the image is getting placed in imageview is from either gallery or server or from inside android studio. Since i dont know how image is being placed in imageview so i want to send image from imageview to firebase storage.

Comment: The image or the link of the image?

Comment: the link of the image

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the authentication process is successful, to store link of the image in the Firebase realtime database, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
usersRef.child(uid).child("downloadURL").setValue(downloadURL);
```

The result in your database will be:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
         |
         --- uid
              |
              ---downloadURL: "https://..."
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar before and this is the code I used
`//Start Uploading to RealTime Database
            StorageReference filepath = mStorageReference.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageURI.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(mImageURI).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadURL = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabaseReference.push();
                    Map<String, String> dataToSave = new HashMap<>();
                    dataToSave.put("title", titleString);
                    dataToSave.put("description", descString);
                    dataToSave.put("image", downloadURL.toString());
                    dataToSave.put("timeStamp", String.valueOf(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    dataToSave.put("userID", mUser.getUid());
                    newPost.setValue(dataToSave);
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(AddPostActivity.this, PostListActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }`

for full code visit [save a picture to firebase database](https://github.com/owolabiezekiel/FirebaseBlog/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/fitn/blog/Activities/AddPostActivity.java)